# what would be the hardware req for an android phone running android 2.1?

Tags: android

i have made a application that will run on android 2.1. i need to make the documentation for the application. For this i need the hardware req of a phone running android 2.1

i would need things like processor speed, RAM etc.

thank you in advance.

Edit:
writing things like "device running 2.1 or higher" will not do as i am going to write that under software requirements.

Comment: There is no hardware requirements because the user cannot customize the hardware. If want to run your software, they will visit their mobile carrier buy a device running Android 2.1 or higher.

Comment: how will the device manufacturers come to know when making the android device? The android people must have put up the req somewhere.

Comment: This is closet you are going to get: http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/development/pdk/docs/system_requirements.html

Answer (score 0):

No; you don't need that.

You should just write

> - Device running Android 2.1 or higher

Once you've written that, there aren't any hardware requirements.

Comment: i was planning to write that under software requirements.

Comment: Once you've written that, you don't actually have any hardware requirements.

Comment: that is a good idea. If i do not find any hardware req, i will write this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know a variety of devices run Android 2.1 and there aren't hard requirements for the hardware. In any case, specifying "requires Android 2.1 or higher" should be sufficient; no one with hardware that can't run 2.1 will be running 2.1.